# Slide backgroundPosition SMOOTH with simple javascript and css3

Tags: javascript, css, transition

How to make background images slide smooth? See my try below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Slide backgroundPosition SMOTH</title>
<style>
#div1 {
    -webkit-transition:background-position 0.1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:background-position 0.1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:background-position 0.1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition:background-position 0.1s ease-in-out;
    transition:background-position 0.1s ease-in-out;
    height:300px;
    background:url("https://www.google.se/images/srpr/logo4w.png") 0 center repeat-x
}
</style>

<script>
window.onload = function(){
    var div1 = document.getElementById('div1');
    var position = 1;

    function slideBackgroundPosition() {
        div1.style.backgroundPosition = '-' + position + 'px';
        position += 1;
    }

    setInterval(slideBackgroundPosition, 100);
};
</script>

<div id=div1></div>
```

Comment: If you're using CSS3 `transition`, what do you want with `setInterval`?

Comment: try to create animation in css3 and apply it with javascript!check how do it here,
http://w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-keyframes.asp

Comment: Bergi, I wanted backup support for older browsers. Brijesh Gajjar, thanks. I think that solved it all :)